# Meteor - Adding image slider using templates not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm using Meteor w/ Twitter bootstrap + IronRouter which looks like

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
Router.map( function (){
    this.route('home', {path: '/'});
    this.route('test', {path: '/test'});
}
```

The layout template (layout.html) looks like:

```
<template name="layout">
    {{>navigation}}
  <div class="container">
    {{>yield}}
  </div>
</template>
```

The navigation template has the navigation bar and drop-down menus, thus shows up on every page.

I want to add an image slider to the test page for which I got the sample code from [Code Lab Carousel](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=carousel)

My /client/test/ directory has the 3 files: test.html, test.js, test.css

test.css looks like:

```
h2{
    margin: 0;     
    color: #666;
    padding-top: 90px;
    font-size: 52px;
    font-family: "trebuchet ms", sans-serif;    
}
.item{
    background: #333;    
    text-align: center;
    height: 300px !important;
}
.carousel{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.bs-example{
    margin: 20px;
}
```

test.html looks like:

```
<template name="test">
    <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
<div class="bs-example">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="4000" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>

    </ol>   
   <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
            <h2>Slide 1</h2>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>First slide label</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h2>Slide 2</h2>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Second slide label</h3>
              <p>Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis gravida odio.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h2>Slide 3</h2>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Third slide label</h3>
              <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>

</div>
```

This doesn't display the slider bar as shown in the codelab. It shows circles instead of arrows. Secondly, the three circles which show which image we're on is also on the right hand side corner.

[image]

So my questions are:

1) How would I fix this circle issue?
2) What's the best guide for fully understanding templates because I'm not clear on the structure of it.

For example, templates can go inside  tags? But would a {{>yield}} only include the template or everything which is inside the body tags?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Meteor/Javascript issue, but rather a CSS one (but who knows!). Is the Glyphicons font being loaded correctly? Use your browser's developer tools to compare the CSS rules applied to *your* page to the ones in the carousel example you linked to.

Comment: I added bootstrap using meteor add bootstrap and I don't think the glyphicons are being loaded properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was glyphicons not being loaded properly. I fixed this by removing bootstap

```
meteor remove bootstrap
```

And then adding bootstrap-3

```
meteor add mizzao:bootstrap-3
```